# Bulk Insert in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I need to extract data from particular database and import it into another database. Both the source and destination DB are SQL server.Source DB retrive more than 510,000 records. But Bulk insert allow only flat file source in SSIS.

Which method is suitable in this case? Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Data Flow Task.  This will allow you create a source and destination of SQL Server.  Look at the OleDb source/destinations. In a data flow you can also perform any transformations or processing that you may require.

Comment: I used dataflow task. But it writes a big transaction file and occupy more space at last hanged up. So can you guide me any other mode to fetch huge records like 510,000 data rows.

Comment: Look at changing your destination database recovery model to Bulk-Logged for the duration of the data import, than changing it back to Full (if that is what is was) once the import is complete.